# Series representation of product of Riemann zeta functions

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I'm trying to solve an exercise in my complex analysis text. The problem is :

If $Re(z)>1$ and $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann zeta function, then show that
$\zeta(z)\zeta(z-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma(k)}{k^z}$.

I've shown that the formula holds for $Re(z)>2$. But I cannot show for $1<Re(z)≤2$. How can I show it?

Comment: It diverges at $z = 2$ [and hence when $Re(z) < 2$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence)